# ElasticSearch filtered query not returning expected/desired score results

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSeach is not returning the desired results when querying for **iPad Mini 3 64GB AT&T**

ElasticSearch highest scored result is **iPad Mini 2 64GB AT&T** and **iPad Mini 3 64GB AT&T** is 5th in the results.

Here is the mapping section for BrandAndDeviceName:

```
"BrandAndDeviceName": {
     "type": "string",
     "fields": {
        "autocomplete": {
           "type": "string",
           "analyzer": "autocomplete"
        }
     }
},
```

And REST call

```
GET /devices/device/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "iPad Mini 3 64GB AT&T",
          "default_field": "BrandAndDeviceName.autocomplete"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": {
              "Active": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 12,
  "from": 0
}
```

This was the top result

```
{
        "_index": "devices",
        "_type": "device",
        "_id": "94698082-d5cb-4f54-829e-dc62e196c894",
        "_score": 9.904099,
        "_source": {
           "DeviceId": "94698082-d5cb-4f54-829e-dc62e196c894",
           "DeviceName": "iPad Mini 2 64GB AT&T",
           "Active": true,
           "Brand": {
              "Id": "7d04b58b-3f2d-4f63-821f-7f081d7f1bd9",
              "Name": "Apple"
           },
           "Category": {
              "CategoryId": "41d45e60-9587-4dd9-828f-5dacf02a499f",
              "CategoryName": "Tablets"
           },
           "DeviceGroup": {
              "Id": "b362318d-5c24-4dd9-a371-3261c6b38ac6",
              "Name": "iPad Mini 2"
           },
           "BrandAndDeviceName": "Apple iPad Mini 2 64GB AT&T"
        }
 },
```

Notice that **iPad Mini 2 64GB AT&T** is returned with the highest score of 9.904099 and the expected document is the 5th one returned with a score of 9.483598

```
{
            "_index": "devices",
            "_type": "device",
            "_id": "5dd038b7-1dea-491d-8d69-fb349970b8a2",
            "_score": 9.483598,
            "_source": {
               "DeviceId": "5dd038b7-1dea-491d-8d69-fb349970b8a2",
               "DeviceName": "iPad Mini 3 64GB AT&T",
               "Active": true,
               "Brand": {
                  "Id": "7d04b58b-3f2d-4f63-821f-7f081d7f1bd9",
                  "Name": "Apple"
               },
               "Category": {
                  "CategoryId": "41d45e60-9587-4dd9-828f-5dacf02a499f",
                  "CategoryName": "Tablets"
               },
               "BrandAndDeviceName": "Apple iPad Mini 3 64GB AT&T"
            }
         },
```

Why would **Apple iPad Mini 2 64GB AT&T** get a higher score than **Apple iPad Mini 3 64GB AT&T**?

Answer (score 1):

Filter queries are unscored; they are simply pass/fail.

> Filters are usually faster than queries because they don’t have to calculate the relevance _score for each document —  the answer is just a boolean “Yes, the document matches the filter” or “No, the document does not match the filter”.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html

If you want scored results, just use a query, rather than a filter.

```
GET /devices/device/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "iPad Mini 3 64GB AT&T",
      "default_field": "BrandAndDeviceName.autocomplete"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "term": {
          "Active": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "size": 12,
  "from": 0
}
```

Comment: I tried the above REST call with same undesired results.  Apple iPad Mini 2 64GB AT&T is still the highest score with 9.907159 and Apple iPad Mini 3 64GB AT&T is the 5th result scored at 9.482012.  Why would the desired document no have the highest score? Thanks!

Comment: Try using `_search?explain` to get a breakdown of how your query is being scored. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html#explain